# Mix of LTR & RTL in Wordpress post titles

Tags: wordpress, right-to-left

I'm developing a site which is basically a Questions/Answers Site in English & Arabic.

Currently, the questions posted in English are not formatted in Arabic version of site and same happens in English version of site that Arabic questions are on left side too.

I want to ask, is there a plugin or custom way to support mix of languages in both language versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you could use some tactics:

For different language pages / posts - install a Language plugin. 
I recommend PolyLang which is both lightweight & easy to configure.

For different styles - use CSS. for example the `:lang()` selector as noted in this article https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/lang/.

also, you could output the language itself in PHP as some sort of custom field - and than control the styles as you wish. example:

```
<div class="question english"> ... </div>

<div class="question arabic"> ... </div>

.question.english { direction: ltr; }
.question.arabic { direction: rtl; }
```

and so on...

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!